# Netbeans NSIS plugin for syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nsis, netbeans-plugins

I am using maven to build my setups based on nsis-maven-plugin. Unfortunately Netbeans does not recognize nsis scripts.

That's why I am looking for a Netbeans NSIS plugin that supports syntax highlighting for .NSI files. Does anybody know about such a plugin?